# Filter through posts via OnClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, frontend

I'm trying to filter through some posts based on their category if a button is clicked. For example I have a button that when clicked the only posts that show up are related to software projects.

I have set up a function called searchHandler that I've passed through to my SidebarOptions component, which has the onclick event. But when I pass it through nothing happens.

Here is the code in the (parent) Home Component where the searchHandler is:

```
function Home() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState(null);

  const searchHandler = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setFilteredPosts(
      value
        ? posts.filter(
            (post) =>
              post.question.question.includes(value)
          )
        : null
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("questions")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setPosts(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            question: doc.data(),
          }))
        )
      );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div></div>
      <Header searchHandler={searchHandler} />
      <div className="home__content">
        <Sidebar searchHandler={searchHandler} />
        <Feed posts={filteredPosts || posts} />
        <Widget />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the (child) Sidebar component that receives it:

```
import React from "react";
import "../Style/Sidebar.css";
import SidebarOptions from "./SidebarOptions";

function Sidebar({ searchHandler }) {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <SidebarOptions searchHandler={searchHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

And here is the (grandchild)SidebarOptions that the function is finally sent to:

```
function SidebarOptions({ searchHandler }) {

  return (
    <div className="sidebarOptions">
      <div className="sidebarOption" onChange={() => searchHandler}>
        <img
          src="https://c.pxhere.com/photos/7b/1a/code_coding_computer_developer_developing_development_macbook_notebook-913320.jpg!d"
          srcset="https://c.pxhere.com/photos/7b/1a/code_coding_computer_developer_developing_development_macbook_notebook-913320.jpg!d"
          alt="Software Projects"
        />
        <p>Software Projects</p>
      </div>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by making a new function called categoryfilter in the Home component that went through the options and looked for the category of the posts in the database:

```
const categoryFilter = (category = "All") => {
    const filtered =
        category === "All"
            ? posts
            : posts.filter(({ question }) => question.option === category);
    setFilteredPosts(filtered);
};
```

I then passed that code as a prop to the sidebarOptions div after cleaning up the code a bit and used it to filter the posts based on the category name:

```
function SidebarOptions({ categoryFilter }) {
    const categories = [
        //Add all projects
        {
            name: "All",
            imgUrl: "",
        },
        {
            name: "Software Project",
            imgUrl:
                "https://c.pxhere.com/photos/7b/1a/code_coding_computer_developer_developing_development_macbook_notebook-913320.jpg!d",
        },
        {
            name: "Engineering Project",
            imgUrl:
                "https://c.pxhere.com/photos/a7/72/gears_cogs_machine_machinery_mechanical_printing_press_gears_and_cogs_technology-818429.jpg!d",
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="sidebarOptions">
            {categories.map((category) => (
                <div
                    className="sidebarOption"
                    onClick={() => categoryFilter(category.name)}
                >
                    {category.imgUrl && (
                        <img
                            src={category.imgUrl}
                            srcSet={category.imgUrl}
                            alt={category.name}
                        />
                    )}

                    <p>{category.name}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
            <div className="sidebarOption">
                <Add />
                <p>Suggest Project Space</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SidebarOptions;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to revisit your `SideBarOptions` component. I wonder if the `onChange` handler makes sense on a `div`. I think it should be `input` rather than a `div` if you want your user to type. Also, you need to call your handler with the value that is typed, here you are not calling the handler (notice the missing `()` after `searchHandler` in your code for `SideBarOptions`). Also, it will be better to add something like a `debounce` so that the filter is not triggered for every character that a user types. It should ideally be triggered once a user stops typing, `debounce` is precisely that.

Putting some code snippet below based on my guess about how it might work.

```js
const SideBarOptions = ({ searchHandler }) => {
  const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState("");
  
  const handleFilter = () => {
    searchHandler(filterText);
  }

  return (
    <div className="sidebarOptions">
      <input name="filterText" value={filterText} onChange={(e) => setFilterText(e.target.value)} />
      <div className="sidebarOption" onChange={() => searchHandler}>
        <img src="https://c.pxhere.com/photos/7b/1a/code_coding_computer_developer_developing_development_macbook_notebook-913320.jpg!d" srcset="https://c.pxhere.com/photos/7b/1a/code_coding_computer_developer_developing_development_macbook_notebook-913320.jpg!d"
          alt="Software Projects"
        />
        <p>Software Projects</p>
        <button onClick={handleFilter}>Filter</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm actually trying to use the div like a button with an onclick effect once it is pressed. I would like the function to automatically filter for "Software Projects" instead of me needing to type it.